# Cannot implicitly convert type SelectListItem to List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ViewModel:

```
public class ReportVM
{
    public WorkSheet worksheet { get; set; }
    public List<WorkReason> workreason { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ReportCreate(int? id)
    {
        var context = new Models.Context();

        var workSheets = context.WorkSheets.FirstOrDefault(ps => ps.WorkSheetId == id);
        var workReasons = context.WorkReasons.Select(w =>
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = w.Name,
                Value = w.WorkReasonId.ToString()
            }
        ).ToList();
        var reportVM = new ReportVM
        {
            workreason = workReasons,
            worksheet = workSheets
        };
        return View(reportVM);
    }
```

I can't populate workReasons from context to workreason in viewmodel. Any advice how figure it out?

**workreason = workReasons** - I have error in this line that says:
cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.list(System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem)' to 'system.collections.generic.list(ProjectE.Models.WorkReason)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign workReasons (of Type List) to the property workreason (of Type List). Change your vm to the following:

```
public class ReportVM
{
    public WorkSheet worksheet { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> workreason { get; set; }
}
```